# Compile a Visual Studio 2010 Project from another project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, mfc, system

I have created a MFC project and I would like to compile another MFC project using it.
I am using the `system()` function to do so but it does not work.

```
system("set PATH=""C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE""  && devenv C:/project_path/Project.sln /Build ");
```

First, I set the path in order to the Windows Prompt to know the `devenv` command then I build my project.
I have tested the command line in a Windows Command prompt and it worked. By using it in my code, it does not recognize the `devenv` command. What am I doing wrong? If there is another way to proceed, could you let me know please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "set" statments is temporary withing the execution of the command itself.
When you exit from the system command all modifications are lost.

If you want to have them persistent you have to use setx like this:

```
setx PATH=%PATH%;"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE" /M
```

N.B. Don't forget the /M at the end.

BUT I dont' think this is what you want to do, because everytime you execute the statment you are going to add the extra path again.

What I suggest you is to eventually store the current PATH in something like OLDPATH and have it back at the end.

```
setX OLDPATH=%PATH% /M
setX PATH=%PATH%; .... /M
devenv C:/project_path/Project.sln /Build
setX PATH=%OLDPATH% /M
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What does the /M mean ? Is it to separate the commands ?

Comment: Is not to separate commands but the /M must be used to set the new values in the system environment, otherwise the commands works like the standard set and memorize the new value in the local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a batch file. You can not use SET with system because it just modificates the current envorinment (read the other answer about SETX).

I don't want to make such environment variables static in my system, because I often have 2008, 2010, 2012 and 2013 installed.

Best way to set all required environment variables is 
CALL "%VS100COMNTOOLS%VSVARS32.BAT"

After that you can easily call DEVENV without using a path.
But all the lines must be in one batch, so that the command processor uses one environment.